# AngularJS $http JSON scraping and security

Tags: angularjs

We are building a big application with **angularJS**
and since everything is client side
we are expecting our app to call all it's data from our backend server through $http and deliver a **JSON** file with all the data

But how can we protect ourselves from scrapers ?
If we are going to give them our data clear in **JSON** and without HTML
are there any levels of protection that can help us communicate with our backend and avoid showing everything to scrapers ?

Answer (score 0):

Login and https ?

For each json requested on the server, check if user is logued. If not, return a 401 (unauthorized) http response.

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be a registered user

Comment: If you publish data or services on the web without any form of login/registration, you publish them as **public**. So i don't understand your initial question, what are scrappers for you ?